# How to pass a [switch] parameter to a PowerShell script from C#?

Tags: c#, powershell

I have this powershell script named testSwitch.ps1:

```
param(
    [switch] $s
)

Return 's= ' + $s
```

When I invoke this script directly in PowerShell like this:

```
.\testSwitch.ps1 -s
```

The output is

```
s= True
```

And it outputs False when the switch is missing.  But when I try to invoke the same script with this C# code:

```
Command command = new Command(@"testSwitch.ps1");

command.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter("s"));

RunspaceConfiguration runspaceConfiguration = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(runspaceConfiguration))
{
    runspace.Open();
    Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
    pipeline.Commands.Add(command);

    IEnumerable<PSObject> psresults = new List<PSObject>();
    psresults = pipeline.Invoke();
    Console.WriteLine(psresults.ToArray()[0].ToString());
}
```

the output is:

```
s= False
```

It seems that the CommandParameter always interprets switch parameters as false, unlike the PowerShell command-line interpreter.  The frustrating thing is that this causes the script to see a value of false for the `[switch]` parameter without throwing any exceptions about not specifying a value.  As opposed to a `[bool]` parameter, which will throw an exception if you do not provide a value in the `CommandParameter` constructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strangely enough, you must specify true as the parameter value, like so:

```
command.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter("s", true));
```

Furthermore, specifying false also works as expected:

```
command.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter("s", false));
```

Returns

```
s= False
```

So, I guess [switch] parameters should be treated exactly like [bool] parameters when invoking from C#!